# JavaScript framework for building out a dynamic but server-side driven frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, knockout.js, javascript-framework

I am looking at building a small app that is more or less several nested lists, and selecting various items in each list will filter the contents of the other nested lists.

**List One**

- Apple

  - Phone

    - iPhone
  - Computer

    - Macbook Air
    - Samsung
  - Phone

    - Galaxy S

**List Two**

- Best Buy

  - Ann Arbor, MI
  - Chicago, IL
- Walmart

  - Lansing, MI

If a user Clicks on "Apple > Phone",  the server will find the associated entiries in list Two for, and update List Two to show only "Best Buy" (assuming Best Buy is the only store selling Phones made by Apple)

My question, is does anyone have a recommendation for what Front end JS library I should use to build this out? This is going to be alot of updating the DOM (the lists) based on AJAX JSON responses from the server.

I took a look at KnockoutJS but things seemed to get messy trying to create a viewModel for each list, and updating it via the KnockoutJS mappings library.

I was thinking about simply using jQuery but Im not a huge fan of building out large sections of the DOM with it (it seems to get ugly quickly).

One thing I would like to avoid (and why I was looking at KnockoutJS) is I dont like writing markup in code. I like the idea of maintaining my Markup in the "HTML", and "binding" the JS data to these elements through a framework.

Also, I hope to use jQuery for all the visual "fluff", event binding, etc.

Thanks

Comment: one option is jquery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up settling on Backbone.js [1]

It seems a bit more flexible than Knockout.js in terms of the bindings. I am using Backbone supported JS Templates for building out each list level. This has required a bit of code, but Backbone is very flexible (thus the bit of code). Im sure this is possible in many other JS frameworks, but I think i've been able to make more progress w Backbone is I dont need a deep understanding of the framework/API/intricacies to make it work - the(my) code may be more verbose, but because of this its easier to piece together how everything works.

[1] http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a partial answer, trying to tackle the concept of "maintaining...Markup in the 'HTML'". I would create a generic menu item in the HTML that can be the template for each menu item, like so:

```
<li id="menuItemTemplate" class="menuItem">
  <span class="menuItemText"></span>
  <ul class="submenu"></ul>
</li>
```

This would not be in a visible place on your page; it would simply be the HTML that gets inserted for each menu item. Then, when you go to add menu items, your JavaScript would be in charge of adding as many `menuItem` elements as you needed in your list. As far as HTML manipulation, JavaScript would only need to do things like add `id` or `class` attributes to organize or style your data, as well as add the text content of each item. A sample implementation might look like this (I love jQuery):

```
function loadMenuItem(text, parentId) {
  // Grab the template
  var newItemHtml = $("#menuItemTemplate")[0];
  // Set its id to something unique
  $(newItemHtml).attr("id", getNextId());
  // Set the text
  $(newItemHtml).find("span.menuItemText").html(text);
  // Put it in the clicked menu
  $(parentId + "ul.submenu").append( newItemHtml );
}
```

In the end, I won't be programming your project, though. I can only give you my preference. If this is going to take a good amount of time, I'd say that the best thing for you to do is to try out all of the frameworks that sound interesting (on a small scale, obviously) to get a general feeling for how you like developing DOM-transforming apps in each one. That'll give you a better idea of which you'll like more as well as introduce you to different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question - still it is worth to take a look at `Kendo UI MVVM`

1. [MVVM using Kendo UI in three simple steps](http://telerikhelper.net/2013/08/09/mvvm-using-kendo-ui-in-three-simple-steps/)
2. [Kendo UI Web MVVM](http://blog.longle.net/2012/07/28/teleriks-kendo-ui-web-mvvm-framework-rocks/)
3. [Understanding MVVM – A Guide For JavaScript Developers](http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/)
4. [MVVM in Kendo UI Walkthrough](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/mvvm-in-kendo-ui)
5. [Build Single Page Apps – Part 7 – MVVM and KnockoutJS](http://www.johnpapa.net/spapost7/)

Comment: More 
[The Kendo MVVM Framework](http://www.packtpub.com/article/the-kendo-mvvm-framework) and
[Single-Page Applications Using KendoUI](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1308071)